# Protocol violation: Unexpected single newline character in chunk size

Tags: java, jersey, httpclient

A 3rd party service is using HttpClient (3.1) to GET a url that I'm serving through Jersey (on tomcat). It is throwing the error in the subject.

This is how I serve the URL:

```
@Path("somepath")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response download(@Context UriInfo uriInfo)  {
    try {
        URL url = // find the actual URL (a file)
        InputStream stream = url.openStream();
        return Response.ok(stream).build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Responses.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Make sure Jersey uses CRLF (`\r\n`) for terminating lines rather than a bare line feed.

Comment: Do you know how? (btw, I think this is a Tomcat issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```
if (url.getScheme().equalsIgnoreCase("file")) {
  File file = new File(url.toURI());
  return Response.ok(file).header("Content-Length", file.length()).build();
} else {
  return Response.seeOther(url);
}
```

Which works for my use case.

Some notes:

- Just returning the file object works if the size of the file is small (somewhere around 2G), but fails for larger files. I assume that somehow chunked length encoding breaks due to integer overflow.
- Trying to return StreamingOutput (suggested in another question) doesn't work for large files either.